# Deriving with higher-kinder type variables

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-kinds

Let's say I have a polymorphic type where one of the parameters is a higher-kinded type (`* -> *`).

```hs
data Tricky m = Tricky { numbers :: m Int, genesis :: m String }
```

Is there a general way of deriving instances for such types without using arcane and unsafe language extensions?

I tried enabling `StandaloneDeriving` so that I could specify the context:

```hs
deriving instance Show (m Int) => Show (Tricky m)
```

But GHC then complains about the constraint being no smaller than the instance head, and points me in the direction of `UndecidableInstances`.

To summarise:

**1.** Should I simply go along with this advice, or is there a better way?

**2.** Are there any proposals to make this process easier?

**3.** Is it somehow wrong-headed to want to derive 'higher-kinded' instances?      Would it be better to derive instances for a few concrete types instead (eg. `Vector`, `[]`, `Set`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** There's nothing unsafe about `UndecidableInstances`.

There's another way to define `Show (Tricky m)`, which is to require the `m` satisfies `forall a. Show a => Show (m a)`. This is captured by a typeclass like

```
class Show1 f where
    showsPrec1 :: Show a => Int -> f a -> ShowS
```

An [even cleverer version of `Show1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Show1) has been added to base 4.9. It's more general since it can be used to show an `m a` when `a` doesn't have a `Show a` instance.

**2.** You've found the right bits and pieces for doing this.

**3.** No, it's right-headed to abstract over even higher-kinded structures like `Vector`, `[]`, and `Set`. Monad transformers have the kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)` and abstract over types of kind `(* -> *)`, the same kind as a functor, to produce types with the same kind as a functor. `Tricky` has kind `(* -> *) -> *`, it takes something with the same kind as a functor and produces an ordinary data type. I call data types of this kind "Models" since they produce a data type abstracting over how it is put together.